# Django: dynamic models

Tags: python, django, django-models

Few words about project: it is a website that creates ads. In admin page we can create a new Category (model in db) and create N different type fields to this category. Then we can create Post in this Category.
I read that django-mutant is a powerful app for this task, but I cannot find many samples(only this: https://github.com/integricho/mutant-sample-app ). But this sample doesn't work to add field:

```
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/tables/38/fields/create/?field_type=29
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mutant/forms.py in __init__, line 60
```

I tried to use "Django dynamic models"( https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels ), but they don't work either:

```
----> 1 model = Model.objects.get(app__name='model1', name='model1')

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    149
    150     def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 151         return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
    152
    153     def get_or_create(self, **kwargs):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    308             raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
    309                 "%s matching query does not exist." %
--> 310                 self.model._meta.object_name)
    311         raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
    312             "get() returned more than one %s -- it returned %s!" %

DoesNotExist: Model matching query does not exist.
```

Where I can see more examples/documentation?
Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Why not use a `ManyToManyField` on the `Category`?

Comment: Ok, Category ManyToManyField to FieldTypes. What can I do with Posts? When I need to create one post, I must create N rows in DB table with post_id and field_type_id. Or no?